# Can't use "attach to process" to debug my Windows Service

Tags: .net, visual-studio

I am trying to debug a Windows Service I wrote by installing it as a service, and then using the "Attach to Process" functionality in Visual Studio 2022 (Version 17.6.4).

Here is the code of my Program.cs:

```
var builder = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
.UseWindowsService(options =>
{
    options.ServiceName = "Example Service";
})
.ConfigureServices((context, services) =>
{
    services.AddSingleton<MyService>();
    services.AddHostedService<WindowsBackgroundService>();
});

IHost host = builder.Build();

host.Run();
```

And here is the ExecuteAsync function (which should be executed after `host.Run()`) in the WindowsBackgroundService Class:

```
protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(150000);
        var exampleString = "exampleString"; //breakpoint HERE
    }
```

I published the Windows Service using these options:
[image]

I installed the service correctly.

Here is what I do to attach the process:

1. I start the windows service
2. In Visual Studio I selected Debug from the Toolbar and then "Attach to Process"
3. From "Available processes" I select my Windows Service (which I can easily find once the service is running) and click "Attach".
4. I wait for the breakpoint (look for comment in code) to be reached.

Step 4 is where it goes wrong. Some seconds after I perform steps 1-3, I get these errors:
[image]
[image]

Along with this Exception message:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x00007FF83E76CF19 (KernelBase.dll) in ExampleService.exe: 0xE0434352 (parameters: 0xFFFFFFFF80131534, 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000, 0x00007FF737E70000).
```

How could this be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

Right after I made the post I remembered having read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/windows-service?pivots=dotnet-6-0#:%7E:text=dotnet%20publish.-,Important,attach%20to%20CoreCLR%20when%20debugging%20a%20%27PublishSingleFile%27%20.NET%206%20app.,-Create%20the%20Windows) on a Microsoft tutorial. Apparently, I can't use a single file if I want to debug stuff using my method.

So, all I had to do to fix this was untick "Produce Single File" in the Profile Settings. It now works as intended.

Here is the new Profile Settings for clarity:
[image]